# How do I make payment with a wallet by copy & pasting an address?

Tags: sending

I purchased bitcoins, I added the wallet, but I do not know how to make a payment? I was told by the website to make a payment by copying and pasting the address? Now what do I do with the address?

Comment: I got it!! Gotta love Youtube!!...